# Self-monitoring a Java process's memory in realtime

Tags: java, memory-management, real-time

How can I monitor a Java process's memory in realtime within the same process? May be have a `callback` whenever the memory of the process goes above certain threshold.

Do we have anything of this sort supported in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
MemoryMXBean memoryMXBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
```

But if you want to get pid of processor, hdd usage, cpu you should use [cigar library](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar)

As i know, there are a few new instruments that allow you to work with memory in the java 9

Comment: But does it allow to add an onChange hook?

Comment: Do you mean do some actions if memory is changed ?

Comment: Yes Anton. Exactly